# ion-toggle checked doesn't wok with ngModel ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular-ngmodel, ion-toggle

Using [(ngModel)] with an ion-toggle component doesn't visually checked the component at the start if the bound value is true. [(ngModel)] attribute works fine but the component is not visually updated at load regarding its value.

Not checked at component load if [(ngModel)] is there

`<ion-toggle checked="true" [(ngModel)]="n" (ionChange)="themestate(n)"></ion-toggle>`

the output will be like

[image: the output will be like]

`<ion-toggle checked="true"  (ionChange)="themestate()"></ion-toggle>`

when I remove ngModel its work like this

[image: when I remove ngModel its work like this]

Answer (score 2):

set `n=true` and assign to ngModel it will select it. I can't figure out what exactly you need

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="n"></ion-toggle>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's still an open [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17830) regarding this.

In Ionic v5, my workaround is to wrap the variable in a setTimeout

My code is something like this

```
// template
     <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="foo"></ion-toggle>

// component
     foo: boolean;
  ngOnInit() {
     setTimeout(() => {
      this.unsettled = true;
      this.paid = true;
     }, 0);
   }
```